# Azure Websites The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly

Tags: php, azure, sqlite, azure-web-app-service

I have php website on azure in free tier. Everything works well except sqlite3 which requires the sqlite3 dll.

I downloaded the dll and did what is said here:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/42bf076d-883e-4818-8585-7bfedff1ff5c/how-to-enable-sqlite3-for-php-in-azure-websites?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

Here is the full error:

> HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error D:\Program Files
>   (x86)\PHP\v7.0\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly

After that i get this error, obviously i do not have `D:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v7.0\php-cgi.exe` in azure websites.

I do not have that path mapped anywhere in my code !

in the php error logs i have :

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\php_sqlite3.php' - The specified module
>   could not be found.  in Unknown on line 0

i do not have a php.ini

Comment: Can you check what is written in log, eg. php_error.log?

Comment: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\php_sqlite3.php' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Shouldn't dynamic libraries (`.dll`) be in `php/ext/` folders? Maybe `php_sqlite3.dll`... Does cgi use `php.ini`, if yes, check there.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the steps in [the link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/42bf076d-883e-4818-8585-7bfedff1ff5c/how-to-enable-sqlite3-for-php-in-azure-websites?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview) which you provided, and it works fine on my side.

Here are detailed steps what I tried:

1. Download `php_sqlite3.dll` which is included with Windows distributions of PHP.

[image]

2. Put `php_sqlite3.dll` into the `D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin` directory on Azure with PTP tool.

[image]

3. Browse to your web app in the [Azure Portal](https://ms.portal.azure.com).
4. Click **Application Settings** and scroll to the **App settings** section.
5. Create a `PHP_EXTENSIONS` key. The value for this key would be: `bin\php_sqlite3.dll`.

[image]

6. Click the **Save** button at the top of the **Web app settings** blade.

Now you can check whether `sqlite3` is installed properly with the output of `phpinfo()` function.

[image]